# Maintain original object reference when re-applying defaults

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I'm replacing this line, which creates a new object extended by defaults and new properties:

```
var myObj = _.extend({}, objDefaults, myObj);
```

With these lines, which do the same thing but keep the original object reference intact:

```
// Save the current properties
curProps = $.extend({}, myObj);
// Clear the current reference
for (prop in myObj) { if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { delete myObj[prop]; } }
// Extend the original reference with defaults and the props
return $.extend(myObj, objDefaults, curProps)
```

Is this a good way to accomplish this? Seems like it's longer than necessary.

EDIT: In case it's unclear what I mean, here's the test for some method you might call `extendInPlace`:

```
var obj2 = myObj;
extendInPlace(myObj);
obj2 === myObj; // still the same reference
```

Comment: it sounds like  var newOb=$.extend({}, objDefaults, myObj) would do what you want, but i'm not sure what you mean by "keep the orig intact"; if you want a new object, then you can only copy the values...

Comment: @dandavis That changes the reference, so `newOb !== myObj`, this is not what it means to keep the original reference. I updated with an example.